# Somar coluna no mysql com agrupamentos

Tags: mysql

Como selecionar o total da *quantidade_pedida* para o *sku_produto*?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei usar **DISTINCT** para agrupar o sku_produto, e faltou somar a quantidade_pedida.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(P.url_img1) AS url_img,
 (PPV.id_cliente) AS id_cliente,
  (PPV.sku_produto) AS sku_produto,
   (P.descricao_curta) AS descicao_produto,
    (PPV.valor_unit) AS valor_unit,
     (PPV.quantidade) AS quantidade_pedida,
      (P.quantidade) AS quantidade_saldo 
FROM pre_pedido PPV
JOIN produtos P ON PPV.sku_produto = P.sku 
WHERE id_cliente = '1' 
ORDER BY PPV.sku_produto
```

Comment: se pensar só na descrição, seria basicamente `select sku_product, sum(quantidade_pedida) from pre_pedido group by sku_produto` , ou seja, soma a quantidade, agrupa o sku. Veja se isso já resolve o problema

Comment: Segui seu exemplo simplificando a query e consegui chegar no resultado desejado. Vou postar a resposta com a correção em meu código.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com o código abaixo;

```
SELECT 
          (P.url_img1) AS url_img,
        (PPV.id_cliente) AS id_cliente,
          (PPV.sku_produto) AS sku_produto,
        (P.descricao_curta) AS descicao_produto,
        (PPV.valor_unit) AS valor_unit,
        sum(PPV.quantidade) AS quantidade_pedida,
        sum(P.quantidade) AS quantidade_saldo
    FROM pre_pedido PPV 
    JOIN produtos P ON P.sku = PPV.sku_produto
    WHERE PPV.id_cliente = '1'
     group by PPV.sku_produto
```